# Why does the Insert() Method remove zeros

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm trying to format a string to a time string format. The PadLeft method is working but after that method I use the Insert method and for some reason it removes the zeros added by the PadLeft:

```
var formatString = data.Rows[i][j].ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
formatString = data.Rows[i][j].ToString().Insert(1, ":").Insert(4, ":");
data.Rows[i][n] = formatString;
```

After the second line of code, the zeros are removed and the colons are added when the Insert method executes.

Hope I explained it thoroughly

Comment: You aren't using the previously padded string stored in `formatString`, you're using the original value

Comment: Try `formatString.Insert(1, ":").Insert(4, ":");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String` in .Net is immutable. Your first line returns a new string and does not modify the value in the table. So you need to continue working with that string and not the value in the table.

```
var formatString = data.Rows[i][j].ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
formatString = formatString.Insert(1, ":").Insert(4, ":");
data.Rows[i][n] = formatString;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the zeroes in the formatString variable, and then, in the second line, you are assigning a new value to that variable, I think you want to do something like:

```
var formatString = data.Rows[i][j].ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
formatString = formatString.Insert(1, ":").Insert(4, ":");
data.Rows[i][n] = formatString;
```